# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{n^n}e^n$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could you give some hint how to check convergence of this series:
 $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{n^n}e^n$ ?

The Root Test is inconclusive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to get the asymptotics of $n!$

Comment: Thanks, but this is not included in my textbook.

Comment: Just use the ratio test.  The answer immediately follows.

Comment: @heropup: no, the ratio test is inconclusive here as the limiting ratio is $1$.

Comment: However, if you happen to know that $(1+1/n)^n \le e$ ...

Comment: O_O  Indeed, I made a mistake.

Comment: @user97484. Even if your textbook does not mention Stirling approximations, I suggest you have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_formula. It is simple and extremely useful as soon as you face problems involving factorials (see the very first reaction to your post by Robert Israel).

Comment: How does Stirling's approximation lead to a result here? Doesn't the root test even using Stirling's approximation lead to the limit 1, so that the root test is inconclusive?

Comment: Not using the root test.  The terms don't go to $0$, so ...

Answer (score 2):

Let $\displaystyle a_n = \frac{n!}{n^n} e^n$. For any $x > 0$, MVT tell us

$$\log(1+x) = \frac{x}{1+y} < x\quad\text{ for some } y \in (0,x)$$

This implies for any $n \ge 1$, we have

$$\log(1+\frac{1}{n}) < \frac{1}{n}\quad\implies\quad (1+\frac{1}{n})^n < e$$

As a result,

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(n+1)n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} e = \frac{e}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n} > 1
\quad\implies\quad a_n > a_1, \forall n > 1
$$

This implies the sequence $a_n$ is bounded away from $0$ and hence the series $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\;$ diverges.

Comment: On which function are you applying MVT ?

Comment: @debanshuratha $\log(1+z)$ for $z$ between $0$ and $x$.